# Copy and paste shape from one sheet to another

Tags: copy, paste, shapes

Can someone tell me why this excel VBA to copy and paste a shape from one sheet to another fails? The shape "StandingsPix" and sheet "Pictures" exist in my workbook and in fact when I record a macro to do this manually, it creates similar code.

It fails in the assignment of "p" with "Object Variable Not Set".  Help greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CopyPictureToScorecard(TargetCells As Range)

Dim p As Shape
Dim p2 As Shape
Dim TargetWS As Worksheet

    Set TargetWS = Sheets("Scorecards")

    p = Sheets("Pictures").Shapes.Range(Array("StandingsPix"))      <== Fails Here

    p.Copy
    TargetWS.Paste

    'make sure the picture is properly centered on the scorecard
    Set p2 = TargetWS.Shapes(TargetWS.Shapes.Count)

            p2.Width = p.Width
            p2.Height = p.Height
            p2.Top = TargetCells.Top + (TargetCells.Height / 2) - (p2.Height / 2)
            p2.Left = TargetCells.Left + (TargetCells.Width / 2) - (p2.Width / 2)
            p2.Line.Visible = False

End Sub
```

When I record a macro doing this manually (successfully!), here is the code that it generated:

```
Sheets("Pictures").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("StandingsPix")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Scorecards").Select
Range("K24").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 621
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -369.75
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyPictureToScorecard(TargetCells As Range)

   Dim p As Shape

   Set p = Sheets("Pictures").Shapes("StandingsPix")

     Sheets("ScoreCards").Shapes.AddShape _
       Type:=p.AutoShapeType, _
       Left:=TargetCells.Top + (TargetCells.Height / 2) - (p2.Height / 2), _
       Top:=TargetCells.Top + (TargetCells.Height / 2) - (p2.Height / 2), _
       Width:=p.Width, _
       Height:=p.Height
    
End Sub
```